# How to use methods from different tables in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to display buttons only to admin users on my posts views but I get this error:

> undefined method `admin?' for nil:NilClass

**Extracted source:**

```
<% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>
  <%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(@post), class: "btn btn-warning" %>
  <%= link_to "Delete", post_path(@post),
                  method: :delete,
                  data: {confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this blog post?"},
                  class: "btn btn-danger" %>
<% end %>
```

**This is my "users" table:**

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "username"
  t.string   "first_last_name"
  t.string   "email"
  t.string   "password_digest"
  t.datetime "created_at",                        null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                        null: false
  t.string   "remember_digest"
  t.boolean  "admin",             default: false
  t.string   "activation_digest"
  t.boolean  "activated",         default: false
  t.datetime "activated_at"
  t.string   "reset_digest"
  t.datetime "reset_sent_at"
  t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  t.index ["username"], name: "index_users_on_username", unique: true
end
```

**This is my "posts" table:**

```
create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.string   "title"
  t.text     "body"
end
```

This is my `current_user` method in my Sessions_helper.rb that is used in my application_controller.rb via `include SessionsHelper`.

```
# Returns true if the given user is the current user.
def current_user?(user)
  user == current_user
end

# Returns the user corresponding to the remember token cookie.
def current_user
  if (user_id = session[:user_id])
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
  elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
    user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
    if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
      log_in user
      @current_user = user
    end
  end
end
```

How do I resolve this error? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Are you logged in? Is the `session[:user_id]` set? Is the `cookies.signed[:user_id]` set? Does the user (`User.find_by(...)`) actually exist? What behaviour are you expecting?

Comment: before testing if the `current_user` is an admin, you should test if the user is authenticated (usually a helper method `logged_in?`)

Comment: No, I am not logged in, but I want the page to load for non-logged in viewers as well, as this is a blog post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before calling #admin? you have to check if that 'current_user' (why not using Devise?) is actually exist. check that the user is actually logged in. if the #present? will return false, it won't even check the #admin? and thus won't throw an exception.

```
<% if current_user.present? && current_user.admin? %>
```

but in general speaking, i really recommend to use **cancancan** gem so you won't repeat yourself with those verifications in the future.

Comment: I am not using Devise as I wanted to learn more and chose to employ code from [Railstutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/updating_and_deleting_users)

Comment: Wow, this actually works great, the blog post is working now, even for non-logged in viewers. I can't thank you enough, I've been stuck on this problem for a solid week now and if I can help you, please let me know!

Comment: NP @Jake Good luck! :)

Comment: Or simply use  <% if current_user.try(:admin?) %>

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you get as an error, means your `current_user` is not set. So try to debug you current_user method, but I think `cookies.signed[:user_id]` or `session[:user_id]` are not set so you can't find any user without `id` !

My advice is to print whole `session[:user_id]` && `cookies.signed[:user_id]` at the top of `current_user` method and you will see where is the concrete issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are comparing two values, If I'm right then you should compare with == instead =
e.g
(user_id = session[:user_id]) should be (user_id == session[:user_id])